# Where to place code that needs to be executed on every request in Kohana 3.1

Tags: kohana, acl

In Kohana 3.1, where is the best place to put code that needs to be be executed on every request? In my case, it needs to manage the ACL so that I can block the request if the user is not authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it to `Controller` class, and implement its `before()` method.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Kohana and I'm not sure how I would do that. Do you mean I should somehow extend the main Controller class? If so, is it possible to do it without modifying the system folder?

Comment: No, just create `Controller` class in your `application/classes`. Never edit anything in `system` dir.